# How to display source code in .ascx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I have an ASP.Net MVC application in which I want to debug jquery/javascript code in Chrome. But I am able to see source code only in .aspx files, not .ascx files. Because some jquery/javascript codes are in .ascx files, I'd like to know how to display source code in .ascx in Chrome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To see the source code of an `ascx` file (which is a partial view or a user control) in the browser, you should first add that `ascx` file to an `aspx` (which is a page) file and then request that `aspx` file from your browser say Google Chrome.

Comment: How to request aspx file from Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot debug ascx files in any browser, because there actually rendered in HTML before they exposed the clients/browsers.

Comment: Is there a way to debug ascx files?